# Select objects from array by undefined value? JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have 6 objects in my array, and 4 of these objects have a parentId key:value

```
myArray[person{}, person{}, person{}, person{}, person{}, person{}]

person{
    name: 'XXX',
    age: 'XXX',
    parentId: 'XXX'
}
```

Can I select the 2 which have no parentId key:value

```
person{
    name: 'XXX',
    age: 'XXX'
}
```

And then put them into a new array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var newArrWithoutParentId = myArray.filter(function(x){
    return !x.hasOwnProperty("parentId");
});
```

Comment: nice and concise, I like it. Just be aware the `filter()` function is only available in IE9+

Comment: @Daft glad to have helped you out! :)